# How to understand this form (interactive (list 'interactive)) in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was found some codes like this,

```
 1 (require 'cl-lib)
 2 (require 'company)
 3 
 4 (defun company-sample-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
 5   (interactive (list 'interactive))
    ...
   )
```

but how to understand line 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to the `interactive` declaration is either a string or an elisp form which, when evaluated, *returns a list of argument values* for the function.

In this instance the declaration uses a form returning a list. The form is:

```
(list 'interactive)
```

which is a form that returns a list of a single item, being the symbol `interactive`

The argument list for the function was:

```
(command &optional arg &rest ignored)
```

Therefore, when this function is called interactively, the argument `command` will have the value `interactive`